# need a location for warehouse or dilapidated building footstep recording

Tags: field, recording, foley, footsteps

I need to record a bunch of footsteps in a dilapidated building.  Ideally with both tile and unfinished hardwood surfaces, and also with a layer of dust and dirt (but not overly dirty or crunchy).

the scene is too long and too exposed to get away with it being done in a foley studio.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a film last year where we needed a abandoned factory location.
the way we ended up getting one was going through demolition companies and found a place that was going to be destroyed an a few months. they didn't charge us or anything.

just watch out for the crackheads though.

Answer (score 1):

I just read that Satellite View of Google Maps is extremely useful when you're searching for unique recording places.

Answer (score 1):

I am in NYC as well, and I know of a few good locations like this, mostly on Long Island. I actually did a library a few years ago of just these kinds of sounds, and most of the footage came from spots on the island. Fair warning; They aren't exactly "open to the public" though. ;) Will shoot you an email.

*Almost forgot! http://abandonednyc.com/

Answer (score 1):

Dude, just record yourself in a foley room.

Footsteps on concrete blocks, metallic surfaces etc or just any surface that a warehouse would include and then add an IR reverb of a warehouse and you are good to go.